# Need help to understand Kafka storage

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new in kafka. From the link : http://notes.stephenholiday.com/Kafka.pdf
It is mentioned:

---

> "Every time a producer publishes a message to a partition, the broker
>   simply appends the message to the last segment file. For better
>   performance, we flush the segment files to disk only after a
>   configurable number of messages have been published or a certain
>   amount of time has elapsed. A message is only exposed to the consumers
>   after it is flushed."

---

Now my question is 
What is segment file here? 
When I create a topic with partition then each partition will have an index file and a .log file.
 is this (.log file) the segment file? if so then it is already in disk so why it is saying "For better performance, we flush the segment files to
disk". if it is flushing to disk then where in the disk it is flushing?
 It seems that until it flush to disk , it is not available to the the consumer. Then we adding some latency to read the message, but why?
Also want help to understand that when consumer wants to read some data then is it reading from disk (partition, segment file) or there is some cache mechanism , if so then how and when data is persisting into the cache?
I am not sure all questions are valid or not, but it will help me understand if anybody can clear it.

Comment: I have the same or similar base question -- What exactly is a log segment? I am looking through the documentation and a pre-release book by some of the Kafka experts. I am missing a clear a definition for segment to understand the rest of the discussions in the docs I am reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can think this segment file as OS pagecache.

> Kafka has a very simple storage layout. Each partition of a topic
>   corresponds to a logical log. Physically, a log is implemented as a
>   set of segment files of equal sizes. Every time a producer publishes a
>   message to a partition, the broker simply appends the message to the
>   last segment file. Segment file is flushed to disk after configurable
>   number of messages has been published or after certain amount of time.
>   Messages are exposed to consumer after it gets flushed.

And also please refer to document below.
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#appvsosflush

> Kafka always immediately writes all data to the filesystem and
>   supports the ability to configure the flush policy that controls when
>   data is forced out of the OS cache and onto disk using the flush. This
>   flush policy can be controlled to force data to disk after a period of
>   time or after a certain number of messages has been written. There are
>   several choices in this configuration.

Don't get confused when you see the filesystem word there, OS pagecache is also a filesystem and the link you have mentioned is really very much outdated.